# How to install AES Crypt - GUI in ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, encryption

I am using ubuntu14.04 am trying to install AES Crypt - GUI via command-line   in my machine

I have tried the installation as per the official documentation but the downloaded file is an exe
https://www.aescrypt.com/download/v3/linux/AESCrypt-GUI-3.11-Linux-x86-Install.gz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unpack the archive and then launch binary installer file from it:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget https://www.aescrypt.com/download/v3/linux/AESCrypt-GUI-3.11-Linux-x86_64-Install.gz
gunzip AESCrypt-GUI-3.11-Linux-x86_64-Install.gz
chmod +x AESCrypt-GUI-3.11-Linux-x86_64-Install
./AESCrypt-GUI-3.11-Linux-x86_64-Install
```

Then enter your sudoer password after prompt

```
[sudo] This program requires administrator privileges.  Please enter your password:
```

and the installer will be launched.

After installation you will have three new commands: *aescrypt*, *aescrypt-gui*, *aescrypt_keygen*. Consider to read their documentation to determine how to use them.